# error in _document.js when run build next js

Tags: reactjs, build, next.js, eslint

I'm getting two errors when I try to yarn run build my nextJS project:

```
3:1  Error: next/document should not be imported outside of pages/_document.js. 
See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-document-import-in-page.  @next/next/no-document-import-in-page
13:38  Error: Component definition is missing display name  react/display-name
```

the first error doesn't make sense to me, see the path of my _document.js:

[image]

the second, doesn'nt uderstand, my _document.js:

```
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
// Import styled components ServerStyleSheet
import { ServerStyleSheet } from "styled-components";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static getInitialProps({ renderPage }) {
    // Step 1: Create an instance of ServerStyleSheet
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();

    // Step 2: Retrieve styles from components in the page
    const page = renderPage(
      (App) => (props) => sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />)
    );

    // Step 3: Extract the styles as <style> tags
    const styleTags = sheet.getStyleElement();

    // Step 4: Pass styleTags as a prop
    return { ...page, styleTags };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <html>
        <Head>
          <title>My app</title>
          {/* Step 5: Output the styles in the head  */}
          {this.props.styleTags}
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}
```

I already tried to install the canary new version (npm install next@11.1.3-canary.15), (saw this solution in another post) but doesn't work.

any tip, please?

Comment: What file are those errors referring to? Are you certain you're not importing `next/document` somewhere other than `_document`?

Comment: yes yes, I have sure, Julio, just in the _document. I saw some people with the same problem as I...

Comment: did you try re-creating _document.js?

Comment: 1 - There is a high probability that you are importing this somewhere else. I would set my project 10 times and it would work 10 times unless you are importing next/document somewhere else too.(I would search for any keywords related to document on my project)
2- You usually need a display name on a component for it to be easily debugged. Every component has a display name. If you don't know why you are using it, just use ` "react/display-name": "off"`  in your eslint config